# iOS - Photos are not loaded and displayed for the first time after giving permission

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, photosframework, phasset

I am using iOS 8 Photos framework to load photo and display them on a custom view. When asked for permission to access photo library, after I clicked "OK", the photo is not loaded until I go back and load this view again. After that everything goes well. My code is like this:

In viewWillAppear():

```
if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == .Authorized {
  loadLibraryPhotos()
} else {
  PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization {
    [weak self] status in
    if let strongSelf = self {
      if status == .Authorized {
        strongSelf.loadLibraryPhotos()
      } else {
        strongSelf.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
        strongSelf.view.layoutIfNeeded()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

loadLibraryPhotos() is loading the most recent photos assets and storing them in `assets: [PHAsset]`. This array is the datasource of a collectionView, which size is not larger than 20.

```
func loadLibraryPhotos() {
var fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate", ascending: false)]

if let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: fetchOptions) {
  fetchResult.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({
    [weak self] asset, index, stop in
    if let strongSelf = self {
      if let asset = asset as? PHAsset {
        strongSelf.assets.append(asset)
        if strongSelf.assets.count == NumberOfMostRecentPhotos {
          stop.memory = ObjCBool(true)
        }
      }
    }
  })
  collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

There are only 2 or 3 photos shown on screen at the same time. As long as I clicked "OK", every time all the photos will be loaded instantly except for the first time. Is there anyone can help on this?

Comment: So you are trying to present the Photo Library, chose an Image, and display it?

Comment: @dannybess I am trying to show the most recent 20 photos in the Photo Library in a UICollectionView.